# Why are my custom email messages sent without styling?

Tags: 7, commerce, emails

I have a [Commerce Kickstart](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart) website working, everything works fine. Recently I wanted to create another notification email once I give an order certain status. Well I created the rule, also created the message (actually I cloned the Commerce Order: order confirmation message)

All the emails sent from my commerce kickstart are with the right styling, they show good, but only the custom message I created does not have any styling, it is sent in html but does not have styling.

I do not understand why my custom message is sent without styles, I copied the styles and html that is in the Commerce Order: order confirmation message, but all the other messages have styles, I could not figure out what's going on.

Comment: what do you mean with 'does not have any styling'? is it only the styles (CSS) missing, or HTML chunks as well?

Comment: Hi! well only the styles, only the css is missing... I want it to look like the other commerce kickstart emails.

Comment: Have you checked your mail in different mail clients?  (example: gmail, thunderbird outlook) Could be that there is a missed part inside your custom message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I FINALLY found the solution to this problem, commerce kickstart is theming the emails using the mail.css provided for the mime mail module, this file is located in the Omega Kickstart theme that was the one Im using, for some reason my custom messages were not styled using that file, so I did some of research and found [this](https://www.drupal.org/node/958146) post where they explain how to theme mime mail emails, and they reffer to an issue about [using different admin theme than your default theme](https://www.drupal.org/node/374222) so they suggest add the mail.css file to all your themes folders...

Well so what I did was to make a subtheme of the commerce kickstart admin theme and the omeka kickstart theme, then I placed the mail.css file in the css/ folder of both, now my custom messages sent with message notify from rules are sent with the correct styling!!

Thank you!

Comment: Hi thank you! I just marked yours as the correct answer thanks for pay you attention on it and for give me some votes! Rrgards

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from [Rich Email Notifications](https://drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/rich-email-notifications):

> To handle the email notifications, Commerce Kickstart has integrated the [Messages](http://drupal.org/project/message) module and the [Mime](http://drupal.org/project/mimemail) mail module.

Maybe your issue is caused by what is mentioned on that same page, i.e. (bold markup added here):

> [Message Notify](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_notify) allows messages to be sent as emails using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), which Commerce Kickstart happily enables by default. Admittedly, **this functionality is a bit hidden from the average user** and it's in the long term goals to expose more of this functionality to the user interface in a more understandable way.

Comment: Hi, I KNOW it sends the emails using rules!, did you read my question? I created a rule for send an email once an order status is updated using Message Notify, I have the mail.css file in the omega kickstart theme but for some reason my custom message does not get those styles...